# How to wirte a part of <fo:table> in a function

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, xslt-3.0

I have to create many `<fo:table-row>` in a  `<fo:table-body>`. I think it's not nice if I write almost 5 lines of code several times (Maybe 50 times) to create the rows.

Like this:

```
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="6pt">
       <fo:value-of select="row1"/>
   </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="6pt">
       <fo:value-of select="row2"/>
   </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="6pt">
       <fo:value-of select="row3"/>
   </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
....
</fo:table-body>
```

I tried to write a function that writes the <fo:table-row> for me. And I have to call the function every time and pass a parameter.

```
<xsl:function name="fn:createRow">
    <xsl:param name="string1"/>
    
    <fo:table-row>
       <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="6pt">
           <fo:value-of select="$string1"/>
       </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
               
  </xsl:function>
```

And now my XSLT look like this.

```
<fo:table-body>
    <fo:block>
           <fo:value-of select="fn:createRow('row1')"/>
           <fo:value-of select="fn:createRow('row2')"/>
   </fo:block>
</fo:table-body>
```

But I get the error:

*"fo:block" is not a valid child of "fo:table-body"!*

But when I work without <fo:block> I get nothing in the PDF:

```
<fo:table-body>
       <fo:value-of select="fn:createRow('row1')"/>
       <fo:value-of select="fn:createRow('row2')"/>
</fo:table-body>
```

Is there any opportunity to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `xsl:function`, then this is not an XSLT 1.0 question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fo:table-cell` can contain one or more block-level FOs, including `fo:block`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-cell)

You don't show your XML, but if all of the `row*` elements are contained by one element, then in the template for that element, you could do something like:

```
<fo:table>
  <fo:table-body>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="6pt">
          <fo:block>
            <!-- The row* element is the current element here. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates />
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:for-each>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Alternatively, you could make a template for all of the `row*` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'row')]">
  <fo:table-row>
  ...
```

(From this distance, it's not clear why the row elements need separate element names.)

---

When you know the names of the elements that you want to format, you can do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row1, row2, row3" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:template match="row1 | row2 | row3">
  <fo:table-row>
  ...
```

Comment: Tanx, but I dont want to use foreach. Because some of the Elements of XML should not be written in PDF. For every element I would make a Row manually. And instead of using the same code to create Rows.. I want to use a function to creat it. I want to prevent the repeatation of the following 5 lines of code. 
`<fo:table-row> <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="6pt"> <xsl:value-of select="row1"/> </fo:table-cell> </fo:table-row> <fo:table-row> `. "row1" could be use from parameter. Is there any opportunity?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `<fo:value-of select="$string1"/>` you want `<xsl:value-of select="$string1"/>`. I would also check whether a `fo:table-cell` allows inline content, it might be necessary to put a `fo:block` container in the cell which has the `xsl:value-of` element as a child.

Also, for the function calls, don't use `<fo:value-of select="fn:createRow('row1')"/>`, instead, use `<xsl:sequence select="fn:createRow('row1')"/>`.

Also, `fn` is a reserved prefix, for your own functions declare and use your own namespace (e.g. `xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"` and `<xsl:function name="mf:createRow" ...>...</xsl:function>`, then use `<xsl:sequence select="mf:createRow('row1')"/>`.

So an example of the function would be

```
<xsl:function name="mf:createRow">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    
    <fo:table-row>
       <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="6pt">
           <fo:block>
             <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
           </fo:block>
       </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
               
</xsl:function>
```

and you could call it as e.g.

```
  <fo:table-body>
    <xsl:sequence select="(1 to 3) ! ('Row ' || . ) ! mf:createRow(.)"/>
  </fo:table-body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to use <fo:table-row> <fo:table-cell> etc.... multiple times. That's why I want to write them all in one function so that I can use them again and again.
I want to use the following code again and again. 

`<fo:table-row> <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="6pt"> <xsl:value-of select="row1"/> </fo:table-cell> </fo:table-row> <fo:table-row>`

Comment: Well, use `fo:table-row` and `fo:table-cell` as you want and as permitted but understand that you need to put a `fo:block` into a `fo:table-cell`. All my corrections where about making sure you use XSLT  and not XSL-FO where you want a result from XSLT and to use the right XSLT element (i.e. `xsl:sequence`) where you want to call an XSLT function.